# How to call function from another function inside the same script in Powershell/Powershell Core?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Consider the example script code `importer.ps1`

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh

New-Item -Path $profile -Force | Out-Null;

function main {
    if (Test-AlreadyImported) {
        Write-Host "Already Imported.";
    }
    else {
        Add-Content $profile "#My Additions" | Out-Null;
        Add-Content $profile "`$env:PSModulePath = `$env:PSModulePath + `";$PSScriptRoot`";" | Out-Null;
        Write-Host "Import done.";   
    }
}

function Test-AlreadyImported {
    if (Get-Content $profile | Select-String -Quiet "#My Additions") {
        Write-Host "I am true";
        return $true;
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "I am false";
        return $false;
    }
}

main;
```

Expected Output after running 2 times:

```
I am True.
Already Imported.
```

Actual Output after running 2 times:

```
I am false
Import done.
```

If I import the `Test-AlreadyImported` function to Powershell and execute it, then it returns `false`. But in-script it always returns `true`.

What is the conceptual mistake I'm making?

Comment: I would go for debugging and put a breakpoint in the beginning, so I can follow with every single line in the script step by step. This should help you understand what is going on and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Force` for `New-Item` means: Create the item, even if it's already there (overwrite). The newly created file will be empty, thus `Test-AlreadyImported` returns always true.

If you remove the `-Force` parameter, your expected output is returned.

```
New-Item -Path $profile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null;

function main {
    if (Test-AlreadyImported) {
        Write-Host "Already Imported.";
    }
    else {
        Add-Content $profile "#My Additions" | Out-Null;
        Add-Content $profile "`$env:PSModulePath = `$env:PSModulePath + `";$PSScriptRoot`";" | Out-Null;
        Write-Host "Import done.";   
    }
}

function Test-AlreadyImported {
    if (Get-Content $profile | Select-String -Quiet "#My Additions") {
        Write-Host "I am true";
        return $true;
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "I am false";
        return $false;
    }
}

main;
```